# Django ORM "|" operator returning duplicate items

Tags: python, django, django-models

Say I have a Model class that looks something like:

```py
class User:
    ...
    projects = models.ManyToManyField(Project, blank=True)
    subscribed_projects = models.ManyToManyField(Project, blank=True)
```

I have some view logic that returns the contents of both querysets:

```py
    return self.request.user.projects.all() | self.request.user.subscribed_projects.all()
```

In my particular scenario, assume that the same project won't be in both.

Here's the current relationships for one of the users:

```py
>>> me = User.objects.get(id=1)
>>> me.projects.all()
<QuerySet [<Project: A>, <Project: B>, <Project: C>, <Project: D>, <Project: E>]>
>>> me.subscribed_projects.all()
<QuerySet [<Project: F>]>
```

Here's the part I cannot explain:

```py
>>> me.projects.all() | me.subscribed_projects.all()
<QuerySet [<Project: A>, <Project: B>, <Project: C>, <Project: D>, <Project: D>, <Project: E>, <Project: F>]>
```

Project "D" appears twice here, even though it only appears in one of the querysets!

Now, I can achieve the behavior I want by adding `distinct()` or using `union()` instead, but why is it behaving this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`projects` and `subscribed_projects` are two different many to many relations with `Project`, hence when one queries from them there are joins with different intermediate tables. Although I don't know the exact internal working of the `__or__` operator of a queryset, since you don't get an error I can only assume that it will use the joins from both the tables in the combined query.

From the above analysis one can conclude that you end up joining over multiple tables, as it is obvious joins over multiple tables can easily introduce duplicate results. As you already know using `distinct` can solve this problem for you (won't suggest using `union` because then it will limit the possible filters you can make on the unioned query):

```py
queryset = me.projects.all() | me.subscribed_projects.all()
queryset = queryset.distinct()
```